# Serialize an already serialized json string?

Tags: python, json

I have a function writing data to a cache, where the data must be serialized to a json-formatted string. Rather than checking to see if the input `data` is a valid json string (i.e. try-except statement), can I simply always call `json.dumps(data)`? That is, if the input `data` is already serialized to json format, is calling `json.dumps(data)` harmless?

Comment: Try it and see. run dumps on a dict then run it again on the string.

Comment: JSON supports encoding strings, and JSON formatted data is just a string. You'll get doubly-encoded data, but that's not what you care about, is it?

Comment: What do you mean "harmless"? It certainly does change the effect of running the data through a single decode pass, since you then require two passes to get it back to original form.

Comment: If you just want "any valid JSON string" without caring what it means, then in that sense, yes, it's harmless… but then so is just ignoring `data` and using `'{}'` for everything.

Comment: Anyhow, the Right Thing is **not** a try/except statement trying to autodetect content type, but rather to require that anything being passed to the cache already be in a specific form, and fix any code which doesn't follow that requirement.

Comment: End result: You can unconditionally do a `json.dumps()` call when putting content into the cache, but you **must also** unconditionally do a `json.loads()` call when getting content back out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no:

```
json.dumps(json.dumps(a))
```

isn't equivalent to

```
json.dumps(a)
```

since the second one will serialize your a into a string, and the first one will serialize a into a string *and then* serialize this string into a string *representing this string*.

Example:

```
>>> import json
>>> a = { 'foo' : 'bar' }
>>> s_a = json.dumps(a)
>>> s_s_a = json.dumps(s_a)
>>> a
{'foo': 'bar'}
>>> s_a
'{"foo": "bar"}'
>>> s_s_a
'"{\\"foo\\": \\"bar\\"}"'
>>>
```

Comment: So? That's still not going to break anything.

Comment: It will break something if you try and take it out again surely?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That won't do anything _useful_ unless you plan to parse it by recursively calling `json.loads` until it fails, which just reproduces the same problem the OP wanted to avoid. Plus, even then, that will give you the wrong answer if you were trying to, e.g., serialize a string that just happened to be a valid JSON encoding for something, because you'd go one step too far.

Answer (score 2):

> That is, if the input data is already serialized to json format, is calling `json.dumps(data)` harmless?

Well, I suppose it's harmless in the sense that the result will still be a valid JSON string. But in that case, just using `s = '{}'` is even *more* harmless.

Neither one is actually *useful*; `json.dumps(json.dumps(obj))` will not give you something that can be decoded to `obj`, it'll give you something that can be decoded to `json.dumps(obj)`, which is useless.

I suppose you could handle that by calling `json.loads` over and over until it raises, but, besides just reproducing the very thing you wanted to avoid (needing a `try`/`except`), that will do the wrong thing if the actual value you want to send is a string that happens to be a valid JSON encoding of something (e.g., if you asked me "what do I click to format code on SO", and I replied `{}`, and you double-encoded that `"{}"` string, you'd get an empty dict instead of my string), and it will make debugging errors much harder, and so on.

So, no, don't do this.